# Only Numeric Value and Value less then 6 from textbox - js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, numeric

Have build logic for only numeric and value less then 6 ( can be 5.9,4.6 ...but not 6.01 ) should be excepted from input , have tried something and got solution but facing some issue...

**Below Input is dynamic in PHP loop :**

```
<input type="text" name="prd_<?php echo $prd['id']; ?>" id="prd_<?php echo $prd['id']; ?>" onkeypress="return chkvalue(<?php echo $prd['id']; ?>,<?php echo $prd['wgh']; ?>,<?php echo $prd['price']; ?> ); "/>

<input type="text" name="prdinto_<?php echo $prd['id']; ?>" id="prdinto_<?php echo $prd['id']; ?>" />
```

**which result as below :**

```
<input type="text" name="prd_1" id="prd_1" onkeypress="return chkvalue(1,0.50,1430.00); "/> 
<input type="text" name="prdinto_1" id="prdinto_1" />

<input type="text" name="prd_2" id="prd_2" onkeypress="return chkvalue(2,0.20,1130.00); "/> 
<input type="text" name="prdinto_2" id="prdinto_2" />

<input type="text" name="prd_3" id="prd_3" onkeypress="return chkvalue(3,0.55,1340.00); "/> 
<input type="text" name="prdinto_3" id="prdinto_3" />
```

**below tried :**

```
function chkvalue(id,wgh,price)
{ 
    var number = document.getElementById("prd_"+id).value;
    if (isNaN(number.trim())) {
        alert("Enter only numbers.");
        document.getElementById("prd_"+id).value = "";  
    }

    if ( number.trim() > 6 ) {
        alert("Value entered must be 6 or lower.");
        document.getElementById("prd_"+id).value = "";
    }

    var ca = wgh * price;

     document.getElementById("prdinto_"+id).value = ca ;
     //document.getElementById("prdinto_"+id).value = ca;
}
```

**what issue i am facing :**

1} when i type any letter/words in input of prod_1 or prod_2 - i get alert of "Enter only number " but after first letter thats :  if i type a , then no alert but as soon as i type again any letter i get alert... but i don't want like this ..i want at first letter it should identity and make alert

2} second alert " Value entered must be 6 or lower " - here when i type 6.01 then also it take value and no alert ..i want value should be below 6 ...but it can take decimal value like 4.5 or 4.6

3} when i make tab then only it showing alert ,need alert on mouse move , keyup etc....

4} lastly  prdinto_1,prdinto_2,prdinto_3 they not getting value.

Need [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/HD4vM/) - for 1,2,3 point.

[jsffle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0t5jo63/)

also sometime i get "undefined" in textbox

Comment: The loop is not present, you've only shown an input.

Comment: (1) AFAIK, `keypress` occurs before the input of the text, consider using `onkeyup`, actually, a better practice would be to not use inline events, rather use `addEventListener`. (2) Make use of parseFloat to convert it from string to a number.

Comment: why not make use of the input pattern attribute?

Comment: @Script47 , sorry was typing mistake ..have corrected ..pls chk

Comment: @Script47 thanks changed keypress to onkeyup .. and started getting alert at first letters ...but when used parseFloat(number.trim()) ... then no alert ...hence change back to isNaN(number.trim())) .. but last point still not working

Comment: hi document.getElementById("prdinto_"+id).value = ca ; still not working ....getting value on first prdinto_1 but prdinto_2 and prdinto_3 showing 0 value

Comment: now check the code in the answer !

Comment: @user3209031 now it definitely should work!

Comment: if i type in prd_1 as 4.2 ..then i get result in prodinto_1 as 715 ...but if i backspace(on keyboard ) 4.2 ...then also 715 is still seen in prodinto ..where as it should be removed... i know its static ..but i am talking in my dynamic way ..as in my page its coming dynamic value ,..hence i can backspace ... as need to see value as per prd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, instead of onkeypress event, you should use onkeyup event. So use **onkeyup()** method instead of **onkeypress()** method.Then most of the problems will be gone!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="prd_1" name="prd_1" id="prd_1" onkeyup="chkvalue(1,0.50,1430.00)"/> 
          </td>
          <td>
                <input type="text"  placeholder="prdinto_1" name="prdinto_1" id="prdinto_1" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="prd_2" name="prd_2" id="prd_2" onkeyup="chkvalue(2,0.20,30.00); "/> 
          </td>
          <td>
             <input type="text" placeholder="prdinto_2" name="prdinto_2" id="prdinto_2" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
               <input type="text" placeholder="prd_3" name="prd_3" id="prd_3" onkeyup="chkvalue(3,0.55,10.00); "/> 
          </td>
          <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="prdinto_3" name="prdinto_3" id="prdinto_3" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      <script>  
        function chkvalue(id,wgh,price)
    { 
        var number = document.getElementById("prd_"+id).value;
        if (isNaN(parseInt(number.trim()))) {
            alert("Enter only numbers.");
            document.getElementById("prd_"+id).value = "";  
        }

        if ( number.trim() > 6 ) {
            alert("Value entered must be 6 or lower.");
            document.getElementById("prd_"+id).value = "";
        }

        var ca = wgh * price;
        document.getElementById("prdinto_"+id).value = ca;
        //document.getElementById("prdinto_"+id).value = ca;

 if (isNaN(parseInt(number.trim()))) {
            alert("Enter only numbers.");
            document.getElementById("prd_"+id).value = "";  
            document.getElementById("prdinto_"+id).value = "";
        }

    }

    </script>
```

This code works perfectly fine! :) check it out

Comment: *If you don't preffer jquery, use onkeyup() method instead of onkeypress() method.* - But those are both jQuery functions though and you've only addressed issue 1, how about the rest?

Comment: @ Tharushi thanks ...but i cant as prd_1 and prd_2 ..1,2 are dynamic number from database ..hence i cant put it static

Comment: can u help me @ document.getElementById("prdinto_"+id).value = ca ;

Comment: document.getElementById("prdinto_"+id).value = ca  ... but getting value on first prdinto_1 but prdinto_2 and prdinto_3 showing 0 value

Comment: check the code in my answer. I updated it and it works perfectly fine!

Comment: thanks ...but did u notice .. if  there is error of enter numeric or less then 6 ... prd_1,prd_2,prd_3 value become blank but prdinto_1,prdinto_2,prdinto_3 still have value ...i need they also become blank ..hence i  putted document.getElementById("prdinto_"+id).value ="";   ....in if condition but its not working

Comment: if i press backspace then also  var ca = carat * disc;
        document.getElementById("priceval_"+id).value = ca; value remain there ..need it should be removed

Comment: that what i told ..i also putted document.getElementById("prdinto_"+id).value = ""; in if condition ...but its not working .... btw now alert for letter also not working....i means if i type first letter as  "s" then i get alert for only numeric ...but if i type 3s then no alert

Comment: copy and paste the code in my answer.. it works fine

Comment: i means if i type first letter as "s" then i get alert for only numeric ...but if i type 3s then no alert

Comment: also second issue is if i type in prd_1 as 4.2 ..then i get result in prodinto_1 as  715 ...but if i backspace(on keyboard ) 4.2 ...then also 715 is still seen in prodinto ..where as it should be removed

Comment: @TharushiGeethma thanks for support till now ... i think almost all ok now .. just if i type in prd_1 as 4.2 ..then i get result in prodinto_1 as 715 ...but if i backspace(on keyboard ) 4.2 ...then also 715 is still seen in prodinto ..where as it should be removed

Comment: @user3209031 you are welcome! Im glad if i became a help!

Comment: so i can u help me for last/...... if i type in prd_1 as 4.2 ..then i get result in prodinto_1 as 715 ...but if i backspace(on keyboard ) 4.2 ...then also 715 is still seen in prodinto ..where as it should be removed

Comment: That's because the ca value appears in prodinto_1 . var ca = wgh * price;

Comment: wgh =0.50, and price=1430.00.. edit those values as for your need !

Comment: no thats right ...as said i have shown that value static ...but actually its coming dynamic ..hence what if i backspace

Comment: what if i changed  var ca = wgh * price; to  var ca = number * price;
in this if u backspace does it work ?